# How to get past 'ResourceNotFound: Requested resource doesn't exist' error

Tags: python, api, redmine

I want to use python-redmine so I can use Python to access my Redmine projects and issues.  I'm using Python 2.7, python-redmine 2.2.1 and Redmine 3.4.2.stable (Bitnami installation).  But, I'm getting an error I can't resolve.

and the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:/Python/redmineTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    project = redmine.project.get('testproject')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redminelib\managers\base.py", line 87, in get
    raise e
ResourceNotFoundError: Requested resource doesn't exist
```

I've got 'enable REST web service' enabled in Redmine>Settings>API, and the project definitely exists.  I've tried this on my server and on my home PC (not on the network, with a local Redmine) with the same error message on each (same version of Redmine and Python and Python-redmine)

My code is:

```
from redminelib import Redmine
redmine = Redmine('http://srv173', username='myUser', password='myPassword',  version='3.4.2.stable')
project = redmine.project.get('testproject')
```

and the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:/Python/redmineTest.py", line 3, in <module>
    project = redmine.project.get('testproject')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\redminelib\managers\base.py", line 87, in get
    raise e
ResourceNotFoundError: Requested resource doesn't exist
```

I've googled, but not found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue! It got solved when the proper proxy settings were set!

Try setting/unsetting the http/https proxy environment variables!